# Pandas: How to add a level to a multiindex from one multiindex level by splitting?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create a new level by splitting the second level at `|` ?

The initial index:

[image]

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['a|a_unit', 'b|b_unit', 'c|c_unit']],
       codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Desired output:

[image]

What I tried:

```
# plan was to create a new column and use set_index
df.columns.to_frame().iloc[:,1].str.split('|')
```

EDIT:
The reason why my approach did not work was the following:

Initially, I had the values in level 1 of the index separated by '*|*' to make this example simpler, I deleted the `*`. Without the start everything worked well, but with the start, I got an `re` error:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Having proper testcases is really tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
s=df.columns.to_frame().iloc[:,1].str.split('|')
final=(pd.DataFrame(data=df.values,columns=df.columns.get_level_values(0))
                   .T.set_index([s.str[0],s.str[1]],append=True).T)
```

Or:

```
final=(pd.DataFrame(columns=
 pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0),s.str[0],s.str[1]])))
```

---

[image]

Comment: See my edit. Having proper testcases is really tricky sometimes.

Comment: @Moritz Agreed. I have added another way using `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` . Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by anky_91 is quite compact. Here is another solution which also works with this index:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['a*|*a_unit', 'b*|*b_unit', 'c*|*c_unit']],
       codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

    #  clean up the column index to have the same structure as before
    _split = [item.split('*|*') for item in df.columns.to_frame().values[:, 1]]
    _level_0 = df.columns.to_frame().values[:, 0].tolist()

    # get the old feature names (units still missing)
    idx_list = [(item[0], item[1][0], item[1][1]) for item in zip(_level_0, _split)]
    df_1.columns = pd.Index(idx_list)
```

I deleted the `*` for the sake of simplicity but doing so removed the cause why my initial approach (see anky:91's answer):  `df.columns.to_frame().iloc[:,1].str.split('|')` did not work

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to access your levels with `index.get_level_values` and split them into three indices:

```
idx1 = [idx.split('|')[0] for idx in df.index.get_level_values(1)]
idx2 = [idx.split('|')[1] for idx in df.index.get_level_values(1)]
df.index = [df.index.get_level_values(0), idx1, idx2]
```

**Output**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(A, a, a_unit), (A, b, b_unit), (A, c, c_unit), (B, a, a_unit), (B, b, b_unit), (B, c, c_unit), (C, a, a_unit), (C, b, b_unit), (C, c, c_unit), (D, a, a_unit), (D, b, b_unit), (D, c, c_unit)]
```